# How to change several directories' names?

Tags: command-line, directory, rename

I have some directories whose names I want to change to `{00..16}`.

```
$ ls
'FVSFT1092A'         'FVSFT1092I'
'FVSFT1092B'         'FVSFT1092J'
'FVSFT1092C'         'FVSFT1092K'
'FVSFT1092D'         'FVSFT1092L'
'FVSFT1092E'         'FVSFT1092M'
'FVSFT1092F'         'FVSFT1092N'
'FVSFT1092G'         'FVSFT1092O'
'FVSFT1092H'         'FVSFT1092P'
```

Is there any command for this case?

Comment: Can you give an example of old name and new name?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix As I understand it, the goal is to rename each file so the new name consists of two digits and no other characters, so that  `FVSFT1092A` → `01`, `FVSFT1092B` → `02`, and so forth, all the way up to `FVSFT1092P` → `16`. *Alireza Balayi*: But you may want to [edit] to clarify that, since a possible interpretation of the question would be that only the letters `A` through `P` should be changed.

Comment: @EliahKagan You are probably right. Hopefully clarification comes soon and chances are good we can close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be better ways, but this is how I would do it:

```bash
file-rename -n 's/.*/sprintf "%02d", ++our $i/e' FVSFT1092?
```

If your shell tells you that the `file-rename` command does not exist, install the `rename` package.

If you wanted to replace just the last characters, rather than everything in the original names, you could use this instead:

```bash
file-rename -n 's/.$/sprintf "%02d", ++our $i/e' FVSFT1092?
```

**As written, those commands don't rename any files.** When it's time to rename them, remove the `-n`. Before removing `-n`, you should inspect the output. It should show what each file is renamed to. You should also make sure that only the files you actually want to rename, and not other files, are listed. For the first command shown above, it should show this:

```perl
rename(FVSFT1092A, 01)
rename(FVSFT1092B, 02)
rename(FVSFT1092C, 03)
rename(FVSFT1092D, 04)
rename(FVSFT1092E, 05)
rename(FVSFT1092F, 06)
rename(FVSFT1092G, 07)
rename(FVSFT1092H, 08)
rename(FVSFT1092I, 09)
rename(FVSFT1092J, 10)
rename(FVSFT1092K, 11)
rename(FVSFT1092L, 12)
rename(FVSFT1092M, 13)
rename(FVSFT1092N, 14)
rename(FVSFT1092O, 15)
rename(FVSFT1092P, 16)
```

Running it without `-n` actually renames the files. You should pretty much always run `file-rename` (and the related commands `prename` and `rename`) with `-n` first to do a dry run. But in this case it is even more important than usual, because in this case the behavior of the command may behave differently for different locale settings or if you have other similarly named files that you don't want to rename.

---

The way that command works is that the shell expands `FVSFT1092?` into a list of all files in the current directory whose names are `FVSFT1092` followed by any one additional character. This list is passed to the `file-rename` command, which modifies the names according (in the first command shown above) to the Perl expression:

```perl
s/.*/sprintf "%02d", ++our $i/e
```

That renames any filename passed to it to the lowest number not yet used, starting with `1`, and formats it as two digits even if it's less than 10. Therefore it depends on the order in which the filenames are supplied, which in turn depends on what files actually exist in the current directory and what order the shell expands them in.

This should work. In strange corner cases, it won't do what you want, and it's easy to check for that by running the command with `-n` first (as shown above), which you should do anyway to catch any mistakes.

For general information on how the syntax accepted by the `file-rename` command works, I recommend [Bulk renaming files in Ubuntu; the briefest of introductions to the rename command](https://thepcspy.com/read/bulk-rename-files-in-ubuntu/) (by [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli)).

Comment: Oh this `file-rename` utility looks great. If I ever have to bulk rename something (hopefully I don't) I'll check it out. +1

Comment: Thank you a lot, this command did exactly what i wanted to do.
file-rename -n 's/.*/sprintf "%02d", ++our $i/e' FVSFT1092?